# Rails where on unusual subquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, subquery

I already know how to use Rails to create subquery within a `where` condition, like so:

```
Order.where(item_id: Item.select(:id).where(user_id: 10))
```

However, my case is a little bit more tricky as you'll see. I'm trying to convert this query:

```
Post.find_by_sql(
  <<-SQL
    SELECT posts.*
    FROM posts
    WHERE (
      SELECT name
      FROM moderation_events
      WHERE moderable_id = posts.id
        AND moderable_type = 'Post'
      ORDER BY created_at DESC
      LIMIT 1
    ) = 'reported'
  SQL
)
```

into an ActiveRecord/Arel-like(ish) call but couldn't find a way so far, therefore the raw SQL code and the use of `find_by_sql`.

I'm wondering if anyone out there already faced the same issue and if there's a better way to write this query ?

## EDIT

The raw query above is working and returns exactly the result I want. I'm using PostgreSQL.

**Post model**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :moderation_events, as: :moderable, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :moderable
end
```

**ModerationEvent model**

```
class ModerationEvent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :moderable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :post, foreign_key: :moderable_id, inverse_of: :moderation_events
end
```

## EDIT 2

I had tried to used Rails associations to query it, using `includes`, `joins` and the like. However, the query above is very specific and work well with that form. Altering it with a `JOIN` query does not return the expected results.

The `ORDER` and `LIMIT` statement are very important here and cannot be moved outside of it.

A `post` can have multiple `moderation_events`. A moderation event can have multiple `name` (a.k.a type): `reported`, `validated`, `moved` and `deleted`.

Here is what the query is doing:

**Getting all posts having their last moderation event to be a 'reported' event**

I'm not trying to alter the query above because it does works well and fast in our case. I'm just trying to convert it in a more active record fashion without changing it, if possible

Comment: Does that _raw_ query work? What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Don't you have associations in your model that describe the relations between posts and moderation_events? The information you are trying to base your query on doesn't seem like something that can't be done with simple associations...

Comment: As @ShiraElitzur mentioned, this seems like a join query rather than subquery. Using associations should make it easier and solvable.

Comment: Thank you all for your answer. I updated my post to include some info about my models.